# API for face Identification (Android Xamarin)

Tags: android, api, xamarin, nuget-package, facial-identification

What Nuget package should I use for developing an Android app (Xamarin) with face identification element? I tried to use the "Xamarin.microsoft.cognitive.face" package but for some unknown reason, I can't use this in Xamarin. I can't find any answers on the internet for my problem and I'm kinda hopeless. Or maybe can I integrate a Console program with my Android app?

Comment: are you talking specifically about biotmetric login, or a more general face recognition feature?

Comment: general face recognition: I want to identify a person from a persons database that I made.

Comment: The `Xamarin.Cognitive.Face` NuGet package is a third party package that hasn't been maintained for 3 years. I suggest you use the official [`Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Face`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face/2.5.0-preview.1) package instead for a client to interact with the Vision API. You can find the API docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face?view=azure-dotnet and documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Face/

Comment: I tried to use this package, but I can't connect to the API. I got an error  " Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.microsoft.projectoxford.face.rest.HttpPatch>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost;" so I can do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

[Google's Firebase MLKit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces) has face detection as well as other machine learning type abilities.

[Nuget package for Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.ML.Vision/)